# Can Google signed URL generated on one google project can upload bucket object into another google project?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, pre-signed-url

Can Google signed URL generated on one google project can upload bucket object into another google project?

I have used [google-document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-csharp) (Code-sample C#) to upload data to google storage bucket but do not want to upload data into another/different project bucket.
e.g. If service account used to generate Singed URL and google project name is "gcp-project-signed-data", then generated signed url can only upload data to "gcp-project-signed-data" and not any other project even if destination project is different i.e. it must give some access related error message,

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Bucket names are in a global namespace, if your signed URL is for `my-bucket` there is no other bucket with that name in any other project:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#considerations

- The signed URL reflects the permissions of the original (signing) service account. If the service account does not have permissions to write in `other-bucket` then any signed URLs created with that account cannot write to `other-bucket` either.